# Invoke method overloads

Tags: c#

I read the following code on this [microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netstandard-1.6)

```
Type t = typeof(String);

        MethodInfo substr = t.GetMethod("Substring", 
            new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });

        Object result = 
            substr.Invoke("Hello, World!", new Object[] { 7, 5 });
        Console.WriteLine("{0} returned \"{1}\".", substr, result);
```

The problem is that there is not an Invoke(String,Object[]) method in MethodInfo class.
(t.GetMethod returns a MethodInfo object right?)

Also another question: sometimes I see Object(class/datatype) variables declared as object and sometimes declared as Object. Is there any difference?

Comment: The answer to the last question: [Built-in types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types)

Comment: It has an [`Invoke(object, object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netstandard-1.6#system-reflection-methodbase-invoke(system-object-system-object())) method it inherits from `MethodBase`.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first argument of "invoke" is "instance" of type (t). In this sample, it is a "string," but in another sample, it might be int. It is about your starting point. The signature is "object" because you can pass everything (almost) as "object".
2. They are identical.  "object" is C# alias of .NETs "Object" type.